# Fortran Dll import

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke, dllimport

There is a code in Fortran by  [Robert L. Parker and Philip B. Stark](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Estark/Code/sbvq.f):

## FORTRAN

```
      subroutine bv(key, m, n, a, b, bl, bu, x, w, act, zz, istate,  loopA)
      implicit double precision (a-h, o-z)
!      x  is an unknown n-vector
!      a  is a given m by n matrix
!      b  is a given  m-vector 
!      bl is a given n-vector of lower bounds on the components of x.
!      bu is a given n-vector of upper bounds on the components of x.
!      key = 0
!   ---Output parameters:
!      x   the solution vector.
!      w(1)    the minimum 2-norm || a.x-b ||.
!  istate  vector indicating which components of  x  are active 
!  loopA   number of iterations taken in the main loop, Loop A.
!  ---Working  arrays:
!  w      dimension n.               act      dimension m*(mm+2). mm=min(m,n).
!  zz     dimension m.               istate   dimension n+1.
```

I am trying to call that function from a dll in c# like:

## C#

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("bv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    public static extern void bvls(
         int key, //key = 0, the subroutine solves the problem from scratch. If key > 0 the routine initializes using the user's guess about which components of  x  are `active'
         int m,
         int n,
        double[] a, //  m by n matrix
        double[] b, //  m-vector 
        double[] bl, //n-vector of lower bounds on the components of x.
        double[] bu, //n-vector of upper bounds on the components of x.
        ref double[] x, //unknown n-vector
        //Working  arrays:
        ref double[] w,  //dimension n
        double[] act, //dimension m*(mm+2). mm=min(m,n).
         double[] zz, //dimension m
        ref double[] istate, //dimension n+1.
        ref int loopA //   number of iterations taken in the main loop, Loop A.
        );
    
       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] a = new double[3 * 3] { //M*N
                  1.0, 10.0, 10.0,
                  2.0, 18.0, 16.0,
                  1.8, 69.0, 16.0
        };
        double[] b = new double[3]  {  //LDB*NRHS
             4.3, 6.8, 1.0,
        };
        double[] bl = new double[3];
        double[] bu = new double[3];
        double[] x = new double[3];
        double[] w = new double[3];
        double[] act = new double[3* 5];  //dimension m*(mm+2). mm=min(m,n).
        double[] zz = new double[3];
        double[] istate = new double[4];
        int loopA =0;
        Program.bv(0, 3, 3, a, b, bl, bu, ref x, ref w, act, zz, ref istate, ref loopA);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            Console.Write(" \t" + x[j]);
            
    }
}
```

However when executing the code I get

```
EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found. in 'bv' on file 'bv.dll'.
    myProject.Program.bv(Int32 key, Int32 m, Int32 n, Double[] a, Double[] b, Double[] bl, Double[] bu, Double[]& x, Double[]& w, Double[] act, Double[] zz, Double[]& istate, Int32& loopA)
```

Basically I have 2 questions,
How to get this to work? and other question,is it correct the way I defined the function

```
 [DllImport("bv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
            public static extern void bvls(...)
```

based on the routine information of fortran code?

When using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) I get:
[image]

I am suspecting dll is not correct and does not have the routine, Is there a way to check if dll was generated the right way?

### UPDATE

After trying  ILSpy I get following which seems incorrect, could you please suggest how to gen dll file correctly?, Does ILSpy  tells that bvlsFortran is the function I should use? I tried it but couldn't get it to work
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use Dependency Walker to find the name of the function. All your ref arrays must not be ref. istate is int[]. Also, don't post fake code. bv or bvls?

Comment: And take care about Fortran being col major.

Comment: it is bv in the code I added to project, and what about CallingConvention and all ref params, are they correct?

Comment: I don't understand that question

Comment: what I mean is the dllimport code part, I use CallingConvention.Cdecl or CallingConvention.StdCall ? I guess as cdecl cleans stack is better to use?, and in method definition I added ref to variables that routine returns, but I am not sure if all vars must be defined as ref..

Comment: No. None of the arrays are ref. In fact I think none of the params are ref. Remove ref. As for Stdcall or Cdecl, you don't get a choice. What does your compiler docs say?

Comment: You have to add a `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'BV' :: bv` in the fortran subroutine.

Comment: And link to the right function with `[DllImport("bv.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="BV")]` in C#

Comment: It is rather strange that your `bv.dll` links to `mscoree.dll`. What compiler do you use? It seems that the Fortran code has already been compiled to CLR and becomes a managed library. If you can confirm that, maybe you don't need PInvoke at all.

Comment: Take a look at your Fortran DLL using ILSpy or another decompiler. That way, you can confirm if @LexLi is correct, and if so, find the class name to be able to call that function.

Comment: I tried SilverFrost FTN95 to gen dll...

Comment: If you use SilverFrost FTN95, then the library is already a managed one, you should directly add `bv.dll` as a reference on C# side to consume it. http://www.silverfrost.com/11/ftn95/ftn95_fortran_95_for_windows.aspx They almost clearly state that by saying "Silverfrost FTN95 is the only compiler that can produce Microsoft .NET applications".

Comment: How should I call the function is it bvlsFortran ?, could you please post a sample code?

Comment: If I try  `bvlsFortran(key, m, n, a, b, bl, bu, x, w, act, zz, istate, ref loopA);
            Console.WriteLine(loopA);` with @ja72 I get Error 1 'bvlsFortran' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `FORTRAN`:

```
MODULE CALCBV

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: sp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(p=6,r=37)     ! IEEE Single Precision (32-bit)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(p=15,r=307)   ! IEEE Double Precision (64-bit)       

CONTAINS

    subroutine bv(key, m, n, a, b, bl, bu, x, w, act, zz, istate,  loopA)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: bv
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'BV' :: bv
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: key, m, n

    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)   :: key, m, n
    REAL(dp), INTENT(IN)  :: a(m,n), b(m), bl(n), bu(n)
    REAL(dp), INTENT(OUT) :: x(n), w(n)
    REAL(dp), INTENT(IN)  :: act(m,MIN(m,n)+2), zz(m)
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)  :: istate(n+1)
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)  :: loopA

    ! DO CALC HERE

    end subroutine

END MODULE
```

And then call it from `C#` with:

```
[DllImport("bv.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="BV")]
static extern void bvls(
    int key, //key = 0, the subroutine solves the problem from scratch. If key > 0 the routine initializes using the user's guess about which components of  x  are `active'
    int m,
    int n,
    double[] a, //  m by n matrix
    double[] b, //  m-vector 
    double[] bl, //n-vector of lower bounds on the components of x.
    double[] bu, //n-vector of upper bounds on the components of x.
    double[] x, //unknown n-vector
    //Working  arrays:
    double[] w,  //dimension n
    double[] act, //dimension m*(mm+2). mm=min(m,n).
    double[] zz, //dimension m
    int[] istate, //dimension n+1.
    ref int loopA //   number of iterations taken in the main loop, Loop A.
    );

// Test code
static void BVTEST()
{
    int key=0, n=2, m=3;
    double[] a= { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    double[] b= { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 };
    double[] bl= { 0.0, 1.0 };
    double[] bu= { 1.0, 2.0 };
    double[] x=new double[n];
    double[] w=new double[n];
    double[] act=new double[m*Math.Min(m, n)+2];
    double[] zz=new double[m];
    int[] istate=new int[n+1];
    int loopA = 0;
    // Call Fortran .dll
    bvls(key, m, n, a, b, bl, bu, x, w, act, zz, istate, ref loopA);
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Remember arrays are already reference types (the default) so they don't need `ref` keyword. Output values need it like with `loopA`, but passed by value arguments need the `VALUE` attribute declaration in order to avoid passing them with `ref`, like with `key`, `m`, `n`. You might need to fix the size of `act` to something bigger that it is because I am getting some memory corruption in the parameters after this.

This posting should get you going in the right direction. Remember always use `Cdecl` with FORTRAN .dll and **always** use `implicit none` declarations. Compile as `x86` and `Win32` and do not use `AnyCPU`. Declare your exports with the `ALIAS` attirbute in order to show up.

[image: DependecyWalker]

Comment: Could you please comment how you get the dll of that routine, I have not been able to get dll for this routine, Could you please share it?

Comment: Also I found why is having memory corruption on act:
I should be  `double[] act = new double[m * (Math.Min(m, n) + 2)]; ` because in the example its size is 3*2+2=8 instead of being 3*(2+2) =12

Comment: You've mis-read the original code where `istate` is an integer array. I already pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: WHy do you initialize with `double[] istate = new double[4];` then if it is an integer array?

Comment: The export happens when the `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ...` that I use. Did you look at the code to see what is different from your code?

Comment: @ja72 Why do you think istates is double[]?

Comment: Your **C#** code, line 38. And your [tag:fortran] code does not indicate type for `istate`.

Comment: I don't have any C# code in this question. The code in the question uses implicit in such a way that the name istate makes it be integer. Read the question again and look closely at the implicit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean't the poster (cMinor) has C# which declares `istate` as `int`.

Comment: @ja72 As I've been trying to tell you for some time, that does not match the Fortran.

Comment: Pardon my thick head. I edited the code to make `istate` an integer array.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your latest update, it seems that your Fortran compiler has emitted a .net assembly. You should add that as a reference and forget all about the p/invoke. Consume the .net assembly as you would any other.

---

*This is the original answer, commenting on the p/invoke*

There seems to be some confusion in the question over the name of the function. Is it `bv` or `bvls`? In any case the Fortran compiler may decorate it. Use Dependency Walker to find out its name. OK, I see you tried that. It seems that your compilation of the DLL has failed to export the function. You'll need to find out how your particular compiler marks functions for export.

The calling convention could be stdcall or cdecl. That depends on how the DLL was compiled, and the compiler used. IIRC, most Fortran compilers on Windows will use stdcall. Check in the compiler docs.

You used `ref` for a couple of the array parameters. That is not correct. Remove `ref` from the array parameters. Arrays are marshalled as pointer to first element. You never marshal arrays to native by ref since the native code cannot make a managed array.

The `istate` parameter is of type `int[]`. Other than that I think you've got the types correct.

I've not checked how you prepare the parameters. Worth double checking that in due course. You'll certainly need to make sure you respect Fortran's col major storage.

Comment: Could you please suggest a method to gen dll from fortran code, I tried SilverFrost FTN95 however it seems it is not genereting the dll correctly.. I am trying 
compaq visual fortran v6.6

Comment: Sorry. I don't have either of those compilers to hand. Your question doesn't ask about compilation.

Comment: Thank you I will try to make some tests, As the root of problem seems to gen dll

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying to generate a DLL for a small example, making it run, than going for that big FORTRAN code of yours.

In the past I had a some problem creating a FORTRAN DLL and calling it from my C# code.

First thing you should do is get yourself a cool compiler for that FORTRAN code, I used Open Watcom in that time because it has an easy to use IDE. And I generated my dll from it.

Here is the first FORTRAN code that I tryed:

```
*$pragma aux DON "DON" export parm(value*8, reference, reference)


  SUBROUTINE DON(DAA,DBB,DCC)
  REAL*8, DAA,DBB,DCC
  DBB=DAA+1
  DCC=DBB+1 
  RETURN
  END
```

The $pragma directive is for Open Watcom Compiler use only.  So don't mind it if you're gonna be using a different compiler.

This is a simple subroutine for you to test. If you can make that work for you, you're gonna be half your way for making that huge one that you want. :-)

The C# code I used to call it was this one here:

```
[DllImport("Lks.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void DON(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]     double DAA,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DBB,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DCC
        );

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //double TIME = 100.0;
        double DAA = 5.5;
        double DBB = 7;
        double DCC = 9;
        //START( ENERIN, VAL1);
        DON(DAA, DBB, DCC);

        Console.Write("val1 = " + DAA);
        Console.Write("val2 = " + DCC);
        Debug.WriteLine("VAR = " + DBB.ToString());
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
```

So for your case I think you can do almost the same but you will need to watch out for getting the right types on MarshalAs.

This worked for me, and I hope it points you to the right direction. You can get the Open Watcom from here (http://www.openwatcom.org/)

I'm a noob, and this is my first answer so don't mind me if I couldn't help.

-Roiw